# Trace-Determinant Plane

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, determinant, nonlinear-system, trace

I'm a bit confused about why a spiral sink or spiral source in a linearization guarantees that the original, nonlinear system also has a spiral sink or spiral source, respectively.  Let's state the rational for why a center in a linearization is inconclusive on the type of the critical point in the original, nonlinear system.

> If the center in the linearization is the point in the
>   trace-determinant plane ($0$, $D_L$), then the associated point in the
>   nonlinear system may not be ($0$, $D_L$), since the linearization is
>   only an approximation; it may be a nearby point ($T_N$, $D_N$)
>   instead, where $T_N \neq 0$.

My question is, why isn't it possible for there to be a different system of ODEs where ($T_N$, $D_N$) is the linearized point and ($0$, $D_L$) is the nonlinearized point, in which case the spiral sink or spiral source in the linearization would also be inconclusive?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's misleading (and maybe actually the cause of your confusion?) to say that the nonlinear system corresponds to another point in the trace-determinant plane, since “trace” and “determinant” refers specifically to properties of *linear* systems (only). The nonlinear system corresponds to the *same* point in the trace-determinant plane as its linearization; it's just that you have additional nonlinear terms which are not taken into account by looking only at the trace and the determinant.

But anyway, the intuitive explanation goes as follows:

If the trace of the linearized system is zero, then the linear system has closed orbits, which is a very delicate property; the slightest nonlinear perturbation might cause the orbit to **not** return exactly where it started, and instead go into a spiral.

But if the linearized system is a spiral sink, then its orbits are spirals going inwards (the orbits return a bit inwards from where they started, after one lap), and if the perturbation is sufficiently small (which it is if you start close enough to the equilibrium point), then the orbits of the nonlinear system will do the same (maybe they will return a bit further out, but still inwards from where they started, so they too go into a spiral).

Comment: Hmm, to reframe my question then, suppose a nonlinear perturbation causes an otherwise-closed orbit to spiral.  If we record and play such a perturbation in reverse time, the resulting new perturbation transforms a spiral into a closed orbit.  Why can't this reverse perturbation correspond to a different linearized nonlinear system?

Comment: It's not all about a single orbit. If you start with a linear system all of whose orbits are inward spirals, then a nonlinear perturbation might turn some orbit *far out* into a closed orbit (or outward spiral, or whatever), but for all orbits *sufficiently close to the equilibrium*, the nonlinear terms will be much weaker than the linear terms, and therefore cannot overcome the tendency of the linear terms to pull the orbits inwards each lap. On the contrary, if the linear terms are so delicately balanced that all orbits are closed, then the tiniest perturbation might destroy this.